# Error while trying to merge pull requests on github

Tags: git, github

I keep getting this error on github "Pull request creation failed. Validation failed: A pull request already exists for username:ft-branchName". I have tried severally to merge it but it didn't work. Please any ideas on what might be causing it and how to solve the problem?

Comment: You've already created a pull request from the same branch. Try creating a new branch at the same commit (`git checkout -b new-branch`) and creating the pull request from there.

Comment: GitHub is having problems at the moment, that could also be cause - https://twitter.com/githubstatus

Comment: I see... it's really frustrating. Thankyou @MarkusLaire

Comment: @choroba I did that already butit didn't work. Thanks